# Grep Function in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a grep function that filters by the characters after a hyphen in a matrix res.2. There are 49 rows and 7 groups that I need to filter on so I decided to make a for loop. However, when I run the for loop I get NAs. When I replace the [i] with [1] the for loop works for the first element in the state.2nd.ord object. I'm not sure what mistake I'm making.

```
state.2nd.ord <- c("^.+-Aaa$", "^.+-Aa$", "^.+-A$", "^.+-Baa$", "^.+-Ba$", "^.+-B$", "^.+-Caa$")

phij.list <- list()

for (i in state.2nd.ord) {
  # nhij
  nhij <- res.2[grep(state.2nd.ord[i], rownames(res.2)),]
  # nhi
  nhi<- rowSums(res.2[grep(state.2nd.ord[i], rownames(res.2)),])

  # phij estimates
  phij.list[[i]] <- nhij/nhi
  
  # pij
  #pij <- res.1[1,]/sum(res.1[1,])
}
```

**the data (res.2):**

```
    structure(c(2, 6, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0, 10, 17, 11, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 12, 
15, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49, 60, 7, 0, 8, 25, 0, 
41, 141, 21, 2, 7, 11, 0, 4, 18, 11, 0, 1, 4, 0, 8, 6, 0, 3, 
1, 2, 0, 2, 16, 0, 3, 3, 7, 0, 35, 29, 4, 5, 10, 17, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 129, 43, 1, 3, 14, 46, 0, 44, 56, 8, 2, 9, 24, 
0, 11, 7, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 3, 0, 6, 3, 10, 0, 25, 8, 0, 9, 11, 
24, 2, 51, 16, 3, 7, 15, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 54, 16, 
2, 4, 22, 42, 1, 25, 35, 1, 4, 7, 18, 0, 6, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
6, 2, 0, 4, 6, 11, 1, 18, 4, 0, 11, 25, 40, 3, 42, 9, 0, 9, 36, 
60, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 23, 13, 0, 3, 4, 25, 2, 8, 12, 0, 
2, 9, 9, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 16, 20, 8, 5, 6, 0, 
0, 15, 35, 21, 2, 13, 4, 0, 10, 33, 40, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 
1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 10, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 21, 18, 4, 9, 3, 1, 0, 18, 26, 13, 3, 6, 2, 0, 
6, 11, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0, 11, 5, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 6), .Dim = c(49L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(hi = c("A-A", "A-Aa", "A-Aaa", "A-B", "A-Ba", 
"A-Baa", "A-Caa", "Aa-A", "Aa-Aa", "Aa-Aaa", "Aa-B", "Aa-Ba", 
"Aa-Baa", "Aa-Caa", "Aaa-A", "Aaa-Aa", "Aaa-Aaa", "Aaa-B", "Aaa-Ba", 
"Aaa-Baa", "Aaa-Caa", "B-A", "B-Aa", "B-Aaa", "B-B", "B-Ba", 
"B-Baa", "B-Caa", "Ba-A", "Ba-Aa", "Ba-Aaa", "Ba-B", "Ba-Ba", 
"Ba-Baa", "Ba-Caa", "Baa-A", "Baa-Aa", "Baa-Aaa", "Baa-B", "Baa-Ba", 
"Baa-Baa", "Baa-Caa", "Caa-A", "Caa-Aa", "Caa-Aaa", "Caa-B", 
"Caa-Ba", "Caa-Baa", "Caa-Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", 
"Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = "matrix")
```

**data for all.crossings.2:**

```
dput(all.crossings.2)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(49L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    hi = c("A-A", "A-Aa", "A-Aaa", "A-B", "A-Ba", "A-Baa", "A-Caa", 
    "Aa-A", "Aa-Aa", "Aa-Aaa", "Aa-B", "Aa-Ba", "Aa-Baa", "Aa-Caa", 
    "Aaa-A", "Aaa-Aa", "Aaa-Aaa", "Aaa-B", "Aaa-Ba", "Aaa-Baa", 
    "Aaa-Caa", "B-A", "B-Aa", "B-Aaa", "B-B", "B-Ba", "B-Baa", 
    "B-Caa", "Ba-A", "Ba-Aa", "Ba-Aaa", "Ba-B", "Ba-Ba", "Ba-Baa", 
    "Ba-Caa", "Baa-A", "Baa-Aa", "Baa-Aaa", "Baa-B", "Baa-Ba", 
    "Baa-Baa", "Baa-Caa", "Caa-A", "Caa-Aa", "Caa-Aaa", "Caa-B", 
    "Caa-Ba", "Caa-Baa", "Caa-Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", 
    "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = "matrix")
```

Comment: I've updated the code to include the all.crossings.2 data

Comment: I think it's the way I wrote the code. All.crossings just gives me a matrix of all the possible combinations of the 7 rating categories. The zeros in all.crossings.2 are replaced with counts of values from a set of matrices.

Comment: It must be the xtabs formula call that is messing up the dput. I will update the dputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the loop is on the element i.e. `i` is each element instead of sequence and this create an issue because the output to be stored is assigned to `i` when it is intialized as a `NULL` `list`.  Instead, we can initialize the 'phij.list' as a `list` of the same `length` as 'state.2nd.ord' and then do the assignment with `[[i]]` while looping over the sequence of 'state.2nd.ord'

```
phij.list <- vector('list', length(state.2nd.ord))

for (i in seq_along(state.2nd.ord)) {
  # nhij
  nhij <- res.2[grep(state.2nd.ord[i], rownames(res.2)),]
  # nhi
  nhi<- rowSums(res.2[grep(state.2nd.ord[i], rownames(res.2)),])

  # phij estimates
  phij.list[[i]] <- nhij/nhi
  
  
}
```

-output

```
phij.list
#[[1]]
#         j
#hi              Aaa        Aa         A        Baa         Ba   B Caa
#  A-Aaa   0.3750000 0.4375000 0.0625000 0.12500000 0.00000000   0   0
#  Aa-Aaa  0.2682927 0.5121951 0.1951220 0.02439024 0.00000000   0   0
#  Aaa-Aaa 0.3846154 0.2820513 0.2307692 0.07692308 0.02564103   0   0
#  B-Aaa         NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN NaN NaN
#  Ba-Aaa        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN NaN NaN
#  Baa-Aaa 0.2222222 0.4444444 0.3333333 0.00000000 0.00000000   0   0
#  Caa-Aaa       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN NaN NaN

#[[2]]
#        j
#hi              Aaa        Aa         A       Baa         Ba          B Caa
#  A-Aa   0.04255319 0.4255319 0.3049645 0.1134752 0.09219858 0.02127660   0
#  Aa-Aa  0.06415094 0.5320755 0.2113208 0.1320755 0.04528302 0.01509434   0
#  Aaa-Aa 0.27906977 0.4186047 0.1627907 0.1162791 0.02325581 0.00000000   0
#  B-Aa   0.07142857 0.4285714 0.2142857 0.1428571 0.14285714 0.00000000   0
#  Ba-Aa  0.00000000 0.5517241 0.2758621 0.1379310 0.00000000 0.03448276   0
#  Baa-Aa 0.06250000 0.4531250 0.2500000 0.1406250 0.06250000 0.03125000   0
#  Caa-Aa 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.00000000 0.00000000   0

#[[3]]
#       j
#hi              Aaa         Aa         A       Baa         Ba           B         Caa
#  A-A   0.007692308 0.18846154 0.4961538 0.2076923 0.08846154 0.003846154 0.007692308
#  Aa-A  0.077519380 0.31782946 0.3410853 0.1937984 0.06201550 0.007751938 0.000000000
#  Aaa-A 0.086956522 0.17391304 0.4782609 0.2608696 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
#  B-A   0.000000000 0.29629630 0.3333333 0.2222222 0.11111111 0.037037037 0.000000000
#  Ba-A  0.000000000 0.03703704 0.4629630 0.3333333 0.11111111 0.055555556 0.000000000
#  Baa-A 0.006711409 0.23489933 0.3422819 0.2818792 0.08724832 0.040268456 0.006711409
#  Caa-A 0.000000000 0.50000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.000000000

#[[4]]
#         j
#hi               Aaa         Aa         A       Baa        Ba          B        Caa
#  A-Baa   0.01960784 0.16339869 0.3006536 0.2745098 0.1633987 0.06535948 0.01307190
#  Aa-Baa  0.04347826 0.15942029 0.3478261 0.2608696 0.1304348 0.05797101 0.00000000
#  Aaa-Baa 0.16666667 0.66666667 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
#  B-Baa   0.00000000 0.05714286 0.2857143 0.3142857 0.2285714 0.11428571 0.00000000
#  Ba-Baa  0.00000000 0.06481481 0.2222222 0.3703704 0.1944444 0.12037037 0.02777778
#  Baa-Baa 0.01169591 0.09941520 0.2514620 0.3508772 0.2339181 0.05263158 0.00000000
#  Caa-Baa 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.00000000 0.00000000

#[[5]]
#        j
#hi       Aaa         Aa         A        Baa        Ba         B        Caa
#  A-Ba     0 0.15094340 0.2641509 0.41509434 0.0754717 0.0754717 0.01886792
#  Aa-Ba    0 0.21212121 0.2727273 0.21212121 0.2727273 0.0000000 0.03030303
#  Aaa-Ba   0 1.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000
#  B-Ba     0 0.02000000 0.0600000 0.12000000 0.4000000 0.3600000 0.04000000
#  Ba-Ba    0 0.02857143 0.1047619 0.23809524 0.3333333 0.2476190 0.04761905
#  Baa-Ba   0 0.09259259 0.1388889 0.33333333 0.3055556 0.1018519 0.02777778
#  Caa-Ba   0 0.00000000 0.2142857 0.07142857 0.2142857 0.3571429 0.14285714

#[[6]]
#       j
#hi      Aaa         Aa         A        Baa        Ba         B        Caa
#  A-B     0 0.00000000 0.2500000 0.33333333 0.2500000 0.1666667 0.00000000
#  Aa-B    0 0.20000000 0.2000000 0.40000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.00000000
#  Aaa-B NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
#  B-B     0 0.05084746 0.1016949 0.06779661 0.2711864 0.3559322 0.15254237
#  Ba-B    0 0.04761905 0.1428571 0.17460317 0.2380952 0.2857143 0.11111111
#  Baa-B   0 0.12820513 0.1794872 0.23076923 0.2564103 0.1538462 0.05128205
#  Caa-B   0 0.04761905 0.0000000 0.09523810 0.1904762 0.5238095 0.14285714

#[[7]]
#         j
#hi        Aaa        Aa         A        Baa         Ba         B       Caa
#  A-Caa     0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.33333333 0.66666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  Aa-Caa  NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
#  Aaa-Caa NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
#  B-Caa     0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.05263158 0.26315789 0.4736842 0.2105263
#  Ba-Caa    0 0.0000000 0.1428571 0.21428571 0.14285714 0.2142857 0.2857143
#  Baa-Caa   0 0.1428571 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.42857143 0.2857143 0.1428571
#  Caa-Caa   0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.4666667 0.4000000
```